# How to remove a parenthesis from an output in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following output:

The food order cost is:

```
$84.9
()
```

from this function:

```
def foodBill(foodCost: List[Double]) = {
    if (foodCost.length <= 1) {
      println("The food order cost is: ") 
      foodTotal.foreach(x=>println("$"+ x))
    } else { 
      println("The food order for each table is: ") 
      foodCost.foreach(x => println("$"+ x))
    }
}
```

Thus, my question is how to remove the () from the output and have the following:

The food order cost is:
$84.9

Thanks

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @user152468, Im calling it as follows: println(foodBill(foodTotal)) and I'm trying to print out the food bill.

Comment: @user152468, is there a way without using an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
println(foodBill(List(84.9)))
```

you should invoke it just as

```
foodBill(List(84.9))
```

This is not some kind of stringly-typed bash script, printing strings to the standard output is not the same as returning a value.

Comment: @mike It returns `Unit` because every branch of the `if` returns a `Unit`. Each branch returns `Unit` because `foreach` returns `Unit`. That's why you should ascribe the return type explicitly. If you had declared it as `def foodBill(foodCost: List[Double]): Unit`, there wouldn't be any questions.

Comment: I know but why is type being outputted

Comment: What do you mean by "type being outputted"? `()` is not a type. It's the only value of type `Unit`, returned by the `foreach`.

Comment: yes you have answered my question. I thought () this was a type but it was a value. I understand now. Thanks again